# Parse and replace nested pattern in column based on values in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following problem:
I need to replace certain string pattern with a replacement string. This itself is easy using [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ms186862.aspx) but I have the problem that the string pattern can be nested into each other
Example:

```
Select 'p1' as param, 'P1-Value' as paramvalue into #paramvalues
Union 
Select 'p2' as param, 'P2-Value' as paramvalue
Union
Select 'p3' as param, 'P3-Value except $p1$' as paramvalue
Union
Select 'p4' as param, 'P4-Value, $p1$,$p2$, $p3$' as paramvalue
```

Table::

```
 param   paramvalue
 p1      P1-Value
 p2      P2-Value
 p3      P3-Value execpt $p1$
 p4      P4 Value, $p1$,$p2$,$p3$
```

Now I want to replace the `$param$` string pattern in the field paramvalue with the real values. For a single value this can be done using replace:

```
Select param, REPLACE(paramvalue,'$p1$',(Select paramvalue from #paramvalues a where   param = 'p1'))
from #paramvalues b


 param   paramvalue
 p1      P1-Value
 p2      P2-Value
 p3      P3-Value execpt P1-Value
 p4      P4 Value, P1-Value,$p2$,$p3$
```

But it will only replace one level of nesting and also it will not take replaced values into account. I have thought of using nested `Replace` but I would like to keep it dynamic so adding new parameters does not require recoding. Also the nesting level is not defined bevorhand (but I could define it as three for simplicity at the moment). 
I think I need some recursive SQL inside a CTE but can't figure out to get this working.

Final Resultset should look like this:

```
 param   paramvalue
 p1      P1-Value
 p2      P2-Value
 p3      P3-Value execpt P1-Value
 p4      P4 Value, P1-Value,P2-Value,P3-Value execpt P1-Value
```

Sql Server: 2008 R2

Any help appreciated

Comment: Either you need to use CLR for regular expression to replace all with pattern match or loop each value to replace with its parameter

Comment: Do you have a special example in mind when using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function like this that replaces the parameters with their values.

Here's also a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43752/1)

```
create function replace_params (@pvalue varchar(255))
returns varchar(255)
as
begin
declare @string_builder varchar(255) = ''
declare @temp_param varchar(255) = ''
declare @flag as int = 0
declare @i as int = 1
declare @chr char(1)

while (@i <= len(@pvalue))
begin
  set @chr = substring(@pvalue, @i, 1)
  if @flag = 1
  begin
    if @chr = '$'
    begin
      set @string_builder = @string_builder + (select top 1 dbo.replace_params(param_value) from params where param = @temp_param)
      set @temp_param = ''
      set @flag = 0
    end
    else
    begin
      set @temp_param = @temp_param + @chr
    end
  end
  else
  begin
    if @chr = '$' 
    begin
      set @flag = 1
    end
    else 
    begin
      set @string_builder = @string_builder + @chr
    end
  end
  set @i = @i + 1
end

   return(@string_builder)
end
go
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charme. Never thought about using a recursive function. Wanted to upvote but don't have enough reputations yet. Sorry